# Bug with openerp new module XML

Tags: xml, odoo, openerp-7

**init**.py

```
import product_specification
```

**openerp**.py

```
{
'name': "Product Specification",
'version': "1.0",
'author': "iologic",
'category': "Tools",
'depends': ['product'],
'data': ['product_specification.xml'],
'demo': [],
'installable': True,
```

}

product_specification.py

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields
class product_specification(osv.osv):

  _inherit = "product.product"
  _name = "product.specification"

  _columns = {
    'prototype': fields.char('Prototype#', size=20),
    'style': fields.char('Style#', size=20),
    'customer': fields.char('Customer', size=20),
    'body_type': fields.char('Body Type', size=20),
    'program_brand': fields.char('Program/Brand', size=20),
    'color_asstmnt': fields.char('Color Asstmnt', size=200),
    'size_info': fields.integer('Size Info', size=20),
    'description': fields.char('Description', size=500),
    'designer': fields.char('Designer', size=20),
    'factory': fields.char('factory', size=20),
    'pcs_hanger': fields.integer('Pcs/Hanger', size=20),
    'developed_sold': fields.char('Developed/Sold', size=20),

  }


product_specification()
```

product_specification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
  <data>
    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_specification_product">
        <field name="name">product.specification</field>
        <field name="model">product.product</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
          <form string="Create Product Specification" version="7.0">
            <field name="prototype" />
            <field name="style"/>
            <field name="customer"/>
            <field name="body_type" />
            <field name="program_brand"/>
            <field name="color_asstmnt"/>
            <field name="size_info" />
            <field name="description"/>
            <field name="designer"/>
            <field name="factory"/>
            <field name="pcs_hanger" />
            <field name="developed_sold"/>
           </form>
        </field>
    </record>
  </data>
</openerp>
```

Again facing problem with .XML file. I am not clear about .xml file & also with bug fixing too. OpenERP 7 documentation is very low in web. Many are defined in various was. Need some right & working example or complete documentation to solve those confusing problems.

Comment: what is the your problem?

Comment: When i try to install it. It showing that - 

ValidateError

Error occurred while validating the field(s) arch: Invalid XML for View Architecture!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your xml, as you have added your fields in product.specification object so you have to define that in model. and inherit product.product in your object means you can get access to all those fields of product.product in your product.specification object.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
<data>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="product_specification_product">
    <field name="name">product.specification</field>
    <field name="model">product.specification</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
      <form string="Create Product Specification" version="7.0">
        <field name="prototype" />
        <field name="style"/>
        <field name="customer"/>
        <field name="body_type" />
        <field name="program_brand"/>
        <field name="color_asstmnt"/>
        <field name="size_info" />
        <field name="description"/>
        <field name="designer"/>
        <field name="factory"/>
        <field name="pcs_hanger" />
        <field name="developed_sold"/>
       </form>
    </field>
</record>
<record id="product_specification_product_act_window" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Product Specification</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">product.specification</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="product_specification_product"/>
</record>
<menuitem id="menu_product_specification" name="Product Specification" action="product_specification_product_act_window"/>
</data>
</openerp>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: My problem is solved. But a new problem arise. In running module their is no field name / tag to identify which field it is.

Comment: put all those fields in <group> all fields </group> or you can use label tag also. <label for="field_name"/> for example <label for="style"/>

Comment: Can u send me a demo link, how to use group & label tag in openerp.